# Cant share files with navigator.share() Javascript in IOS

Tags: javascript, ios

Im trying to share a file with Navigator.Share(), in android works perfect, but in ios don't work. I can share text but not images. Exist alternativees, or i cant share files in ios?

```
            fetch(text)
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.blob()
            })
            .then(function(blob) {
            
                var file = new File([blob], "image.png", {type: blob.type});
                var filesArray = [file];
                var shareData = { files: filesArray };
            
            
                 
                 navigator.share({
                    url: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0003/6270/9002/files/toshare-05.png?v=1621420555',
                    });
                
                console.log("Your system doesn't support sharing files.");
                

            });
        }
    }
```